# Как сделать debayer для картинки с помощью FFMpeg? (.exe file)

Tags: ffmpeg

У меня есть изображение для которого нужно сделать debayer, мне почему то казалось, что FFMpeg делает это по дефолту и я попробовал самую простую команду

```
ffmpeg -i input.bmp output.png
```

но output.png получается серым, что говорит о том, что FFMpeg не делает это по умолчанию, я проверил как это сделать, но в гугл почти нет ничего об этом...

Вот картинка для примера(она слишком большая, чтоб загрузить ее сюда)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V8HwOuIo9PBX3ix0eKFQFGimskU_H0mN/view?usp=sharing

Как это сделать?

**UPD**

```
ffmpeg -i D:\Buffer\Bayer\Time0000000_img.bmp -f rawvideo D:\Buffer\Bayer\bmp\test10.bin -hide_banner
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 4104x3006 -pix_fmt bayer_rggb8 -i D:\Buffer\Bayer\bmp\test10.bin -pix_fmt rgb24 -frames 1 D:\Buffer\Bayer\bmp\result.bmp -hide_banner
```

получаю вот такую ошибку

```
Truncating packet of size 12336624 to 5067009
[rawvideo @ 0000028528570fc0] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'D:\Buffer\Bayer\bmp\test10.bin':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2467324 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo ([186]RG[8] / 0x84752BA), bayer_rggb8, 4104x3006, 2467324 kb/s, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (rawvideo (native) -> bmp (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
D:\Buffer\Bayer\bmp\test10.bin: corrupt input packet in stream 0
[rawvideo @ 000002852857d4c0] Invalid buffer size, packet size 5067008 < expected frame_size 12336624
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid argument
Incompatible pixel format 'rgb24' for codec 'bmp', auto-selecting format 'bgr24'
Output #0, image2, to 'D:\Buffer\Bayer\bmp\result.bmp':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgr24, 4104x3006, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 bmp
frame=    0 fps=0.0 q=0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A speed=   0x
video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
Output file is empty, nothing was encoded (check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
Conversion failed!
```

Но если меняю разрешение то ошибки нет, но результат не верный

```
ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 1920x1080 -pix_fmt bayer_rggb8 -i D:\Buffer\Bayer\bmp\test10.bin -pix_fmt rgb24 -frames 1 D:\Buffer\Bayer\bmp\result.bmp -hide_banner
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непонятно, почему вы решили, что ffmpeg должен делать это по умолчанию, особенно с учётом того, что BMP в принципе не предназначен для хранения bayer-картинок...

Но раз уж вы каким-то чудом умудрились использовать неправильный формат, значит придётся каким-то образом заставить ffmpeg использовать вручную прописанный формат вместо автоматически определённого.

Я не нашёл в ffmpeg готовой опции для этого, но можно схитрить через промежуточный raw-файл. Сперва сохраняем сырые значения пикселей:

```
ffmpeg -i Time0000005_img.bmp -pix_fmt gray -f rawvideo raw.bin
```

Потом считываем эти сырые значения в нужном bayer-формате и сохраняем в RGB:

```
ffmpeg \
  -f rawvideo -video_size 4104x3006 -pix_fmt bayer_rggb8 -i raw.bin \
  -pix_fmt rgb24 -frames 1 result.bmp
```

Raw-файл не имеет в себе информации о размере (он вообще не содержит никакой информации, кроме собственно значений пикселей), поэтому важно, чтобы размер, указанный в опции `-video_size` на входе, совпадал с реальным размером исходной картинки, иначе эти raw-пиксели лягут неправильно и получится [вот такое вот](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQH7W.jpg). Если нужно изменить размер картинки, то это следует делать фильтром уже на выводе (`-vf scale=1474:1080`)

В результате на чётких контурах остаётся виден «шахматный» паттерн фильтра Байера, требующий дальнейшей постобработки, да и баланс белого подкрутить не помешает, но по крайней мере цвета хотя бы похожи на реальные:

[image]

Comment: я добавил upd в вопрос, что то пошло не по плану. И еще я хотел уточнить, а почему выбирается именно такое разрешние `4104x3006` ?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko потому что у показанной вами картинки оно именно такое

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko дополнил ответ

Comment: у меня так же получилось сделать это в одну строку `ffmpeg -i D:\Buffer\Bayer\ddd\Time0000005_img.bmp -f rawvideo pipe: | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -s 4104x3006 -pix_fmt bayer_rggb8 -i pipe: -pix_fmt bgr24 -frames 1 D:\Buffer\Bayer\bmp\result3.bmp -hide_banner` , еще изменил `rgb` на `bgr`

Comment: Я выяснил, что то интересное, когда я делаю эту команду для сета картинок (200шт.) то начиная с ~10 картинка начинает сдвигаться... То есть я открываю 11е изображение и я вижу половину фрейма 11го и половину 12го (или это две половины одного и того же фрейма просто поменяны местами). Я поменял команду на вот такую и все заработало `ffmpeg -y -i Time0000005_img.bmp -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size 4104x3006 -i pipe: rgb.png`  почему такое может происходить?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko Вероятно, потому что одна из ваших картинок технически считается цветной, а пиксели в цветных картинках имеют другой формат (в rgb24 три байта на цвет вместо одного в gray)

Comment: можете еще глянуть на вот этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1283700/195957

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko а, я кажется понял что на самом деле происходит — вы пытаетесь обработать несколько картинок сразу (`Time%7d_img.bmp`), и здесь всплывает проигнорированный мной нюанс, что в ваших картинках формат пикселей `pal8`, который в конце себя имеет дополнительные данные (вероятно, это цвета из используемой палитры), которые понемногу и сдвигают кадры. Преобразование из `pal8` в `gray` убирает эти дополнительные данные, смещение прекращается и всё становится ровненько

Comment: я только что выяснил (методом тыка), что вот этот параметр влияет `-vf format=gray` и кстати во втором вопросе его тоже нужно добавить, а то там тоже сдвигается картинка

Comment: можете глянуть на этот вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1288208/195957 ?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko не могу, в C++ я уже не умею и в colorspace не очень разбираюсь