# Как слить две команды FFMpeg в одну? (pipe)

Tags: ffmpeg

У меня есть сет из 100 баер изображений (для примера https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V8HwOuIo9PBX3ix0eKFQFGimskU_H0mN/view?usp=sharing) мне нужно сделать следующее

1. дебаер
2. скомпресить из в файл `.h264`

для этого я использую две команды

для дебаера

```
ffmpeg -y -i D:\Buffer\Bayer\Time%7d_img.bmp -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: -hide_banner | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size 4104x3006 -i pipe: -frames 100 D:\Buffer\res\result%7d.png -hide_banner
```

для компресии

```
ffmpeg -framerate 30 -i D:\Buffer\res\result%7d.png -c:v hevc_nvenc -qp 0 D:\Buffer\res264\test5.h264 -hide_banner
```

и это работает. Теперь я попробовал соеденить эти две команды и вот, что вышло

```
ffmpeg -y -i D:\Buffer\Bayer\Time%7d_img.bmp -vf format=gray -f rawvideo pipe: -hide_banner | ffmpeg -y -f rawvideo -pixel_format bayer_rggb8 -video_size 4104x3006 pipe: -hide_banner | ffmpeg -c:v hevc_nvenc -qp 0 -i pipe D:\Buffer\res264\test5.h264 -hide_banner
```

но получаю вот такую ошибку

```
Input #0, image2, from 'D:\Buffer\Bayer\Time%7d_img.bmp':
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'pipe:':  Duration:
00:00:40.0Output file #0 does not contain any stream0
, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/AUnknown decoder 'hevc_nvenc'

    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, pal8, 2464x2056, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (bmp (native) -> rawvideo (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, rawvideo, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (Y800 / 0x30303859), gray, 2464x2056, q=2-31, 1013196 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 rawvideo
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Invalid argument
Error writing trailer of pipe:: Invalid argument
frame=    1 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=    4947kB time=00:00:00.04 bitrate=1013196.8kbits/s speed=   2x
video:4947kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.000000%
Conversion failed!
```

как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет необходимости сохранять промежуточные png-файлы, если они всё равно потом пойдут в видео, можно сразу писать видео:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel error -i 'Time%7d_img.bmp' -pix_fmt gray -f rawvideo pipe: | \
  ffmpeg -f rawvideo -framerate 30 -video_size 4104x3006 -pix_fmt bayer_rggb8 -i pipe: \
  -c:v hevc_nvenc -qp 0 -y test5.h264
```

<sup>*P.S. Если кто из спецов по ffmpeg сюда заглянет — было бы неплохо как-нибудь уложить дебайеризацию в одну команду, см. [Как сделать debayer для картинки с помощью FFMpeg?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1283336)*</sup>

Comment: мне еще доплнительно нужно добавить параметры от куда начать и сколько фреймов взять, для этого я добавил вот такие параметры `-start_number 1 -vframes 100` вроде как все работает.  `ffmpeg -loglevel error -start_number 1 -i %input_img% -vframes 100 -vf format=gray......`